# Resolving exception when running .exe with Unity but not when running release in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-container, prism

I changed my object to extend an abstract class instead of an interface

```
public interface IService {}

public abstract class BaseService : IService {}

public class ConcreteServiceA : BaseService {

    public ConcreteServiceA(IUnityContainer container) {
        container.RegisterInstance<IService>("ConcreteServiceA", this);
    }

}

public class ConcreteServiceB : BaseService {

    public ConcreteServiceB(IUnityContainer container) {
        container.RegisterInstance<IService>("ConcreteServiceB", this);
    }

}
```

Running this in release in Visual studio works great and I get the two different instances of IService by using their name. However, when I later run the app.exe file, the following type of code gives an exception

```
private IService GetInstance(string name) {
    return m_Container.Resolve<IService>(name);
}
```

The root exception says:

```
InvalidOperationException - The current type, Common.Interfaces.IService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping.
```

The issue started when I introduced the BaseService abstract class. The strange thing is that it works without issues when starting a Release build in VS but not when I run the .exe file.

**EDIT: Tried the Debug build and that .exe file runs also without issue so it seems to only be happiening in the Release-build**

**EDIT2: The objects are instanced from modules detected and initialized in the bootstrapper**

Comment: I don't know if you just missed in your example code but either the base service or the concrete services must implement the interface.
If you have the interface implementation, make sure that you are passing a name to the resolve method that actually has been registered in the container. If name does not exist in the container, you will get that exception.

Comment: Hi, yeah I just forgot that in my example, thanks for noticing. The strange issue is that it all works when i just run with F5 in release in Visual Studio. Also works when I build for debug and run the .exe file. However, it does not work when I run the .exe file of the release build. And it was introduced when we added an abstract base-class

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to resolve a service that registers itself with the container when it is created.  So, how will you be able to register it without resolving it first, and how can you resolve it without registering it first?  Pull you registration out of the ctor of the service, and place it somewhere else like in the ConfigureCOntainer override.

Comment: They are actually instanced by various modules. Sorry, forgot to mention that. They are registrering themselves as instances in the container.

Comment: So are you manually creating them and passing in the IUNityContainer via the ctor?

Comment: Yes exactly. They register themselves as instances in the container